# jQuery to target table row by class after specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have a table with six rows:

```
<table>
    <tr class="current">
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="details">
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="details">
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I would like to do is target the row with class="details". Since I have multiple rows with that class on the page, I need to target the row that is after the class "current".

I have tried using .find() and .closest(), but since my target is not an ancestor or descendant, these do not work. I tried using .next() also, but did not have any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) is not working because `.details` is not the immediate sibling of `.current`. Using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) does not work simply because it starts from the element itself and then travels up the DOM (searches for ancestors), and does not look among the siblings nested in the same level.

Basically we are trying to emulate the behavior of the general sibling selector `~` in CSS, with the exception that is has to be first occurence. Therefore, we use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), and pair that up with [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) that returns the first element that satisfies the `.nextAll()`, i.e.

```
// jQuery-based DOM transversal
$('.current').nextAll('.details').first();
```

You can of course use CSS, but I suspect that would be less efficient. Also, by using CSS selectors you will not be able to transverse the DOM by chaining additional methods:

```
// CSS-based selection
$('.current ~ .details:first');
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.current').nextAll('.details').first().css('background-color','#eee');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="current">
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="details">
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="details">
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @ericbelldesigns Sorry, I misunderstood your question and didn't see that there is a `<tr>` without class between `.current` and `.details`. Updated my answer. TL;DR use `.nextAll().first()`.